# Issues reading text file from hdfs using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I have recently started learning hadoop and spark and I am having issues reading a text file from hdfs. I have followed through with several articles here but still not getting it. I would be glad with an assist.

`hadoop fs -ls /user/training
-rw-r--r--   1 training supergroup     264875 2019-07-10 16:53 /user/training/book.txt`

```
scala> val readme= sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/training/book.txt")
scala> val readme= sc.textFile("/user/training/book.txt")
scala> val readme= sc.textFile("/book.txt")

scala> readme.count
```

I tried all the above codes but kept getting errors

Comment: Is this working? `"hdfs:///user/training/book.txt"` BTW what error occurs?

Comment: @Lamanus org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/lee.txt
this error

Comment: this is what i got when I tried your approach : java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:/user/training/book.txt

Comment: Check you HDFS data node URL, could you try this as well hdfs://localhost:9000/user/training/book.txt